why is Arduino serial usb disconnected with error "not an MTP device"
Today I could suddenly not attach my Arduino zero to Arduino IDE because usb system rejects the device.
I've been using Arduino IDE for years so probably there is new fix for something else in the usb system that picks it up and rejects. I am used to handling new USB-devices in the udev config files so I had a look and found that there is an entry for arduino in /etc/udev/rules.d/70-snap.core.rules , which is the correct vendor id.
ATTRS{idVendor}=="2341", ENV{ID_MM_DEVICE_IGNORE}="1"
So I tried a new entry without changing symptoms:
60-arduino.rules: SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2341", MODE="666", GOTO="libmtp_rules_end"
Symptoms in the kernel log are cyclically recurring messages :
Jun  6 15:31:46 ghia kernel: [  879.269801] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 126
Jun  6 15:31:49 ghia kernel: [  882.099257] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 127 using xhci_hcd`
Jun  6 15:31:49 ghia kernel: [  882.276896] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=2341, idProduct=804d, bcdDevice= 1.00
Jun  6 15:31:49 ghia kernel: [  882.276904] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Jun  6 15:31:49 ghia kernel: [  882.276907] usb 1-2: Product: Arduino Zero
Jun  6 15:31:49 ghia kernel: [  882.276911] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Arduino LLC
Jun  6 15:31:49 ghia kernel: [  882.276914] usb 1-2: SerialNumber: 2ABBC01F5055344A342E3120FF04121B
Jun  6 15:31:49 ghia kernel: [  882.298994] cdc_acm 1-2:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
Jun  6 15:31:49 ghia mtp-probe: checking bus 1, device 127: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:05:00.3/usb1/1-2"
Jun  6 15:31:49 ghia mtp-probe: bus: 1, device: 127 was not an MTP device

EDIT: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS running kernel 5.15.0-107- generic.
Edit2: It turns out that other Arduino devices like Zero, MKRZero and MKR1500 as well as Arduino Zero clone HW-799 is not disconnected. So the remaining problem is Arduino Zero clone HW-819 is disconnected either by itself or by linux.
The 'not an MTP device' syslog message seems to be not related.

The solution to the problem was in the device that was in a state that did not connect properly. Set the device in boot mode by double-press the reset-button and then it connected. Uploading new application software made it stay connected to USB.
